# Recursive function to calculate sum of 1 to n?

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, sum

This is what I've got and I'm not sure why it's not working:

```
def sum(n):
    if n > 0:
        print(n)
        return sum(n) + sum(n-1)
    else:
        print("done doodly")

number = int(input(":  "))
sum(number)
```

For example if the user inputs `5`, I want the program to calculate the sum of 5+4+3+2+1. What am I doing wrong?

---

<sup>For the ***non-recursive*** version of this question, see [Sum of the integers from 1 to n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43901484/6045800)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Two things:

- Calling `sum(n)` when computing `sum` for `n` won't do you much good because you'll recurse indefinitely. So the line `return sum(n)+sum(n-1)` is incorrect; it needs to be `n` plus the sum of the `n - 1` other values. This also makes sense as that's what you want to compute.
- You need to return a value for the base case and for the recursive case.

As such you can simplify your code to:

```
def sum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return n + sum(n - 1)
```

Comment: Now how would I print the sum ? @Simeon Visser

Comment: `print sum(n)` - let the return value of `sum` be the argument to `print`.

Comment: @kiasy yes, let `sum` compute the result and then, after it is done, print it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `return` when `n==0` (in your `else`)

```
>>> def Sum(n):
...   if not n:
...     return 0
...   else:
...     return n + Sum(n-1)
... 
>>> Sum(5)
15
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is a wrong way to calculate the sum of the first n number, since you make the computer to do `n` calculations (This runs in O(n) time.) which is a waste.

You could even use the built-in `sum()` function with `range()`, but despite this code is looking nice and clean, it still runs in O(n):

```
>>> def sum_(n):
...     return sum(range(1, n+1))
...
>>> sum_(5)
15
```

Instead recursion I recommend using the equation of sum of [arithmetic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), since It runs in O(1) time:

```
>>> def sum_(n):
...     return (n + n**2)//2
...
>>> sum_(5)
15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *complicate* your code to:

```
def my_sum(n, first=0):
    if n == first:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + my_sum(n-1, (n+first)//2) + my_sum((n+first)//2, first)
```

The advantage is that now you only use `log(n)` stack instead of `n`stack

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the below mathematical function(complexity O(1)) instead of using recursion(complexity O(n))

```
def sum(n):
    return (n*(n+1))/2
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using Recursion

```py
def sum_upto(n):
  return n + sum_upto(n-1) if n else 0

sum_upto(100)
```

```
5050
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below snippet in regards to your request. I certainly hope this helps. Cheers!

```
def recursive_sum(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else n + recursive_sum(n-1)

# Please change the number to test other scenarios.
num = 100

if num < 0:
   print("Please enter a positive number")
else:
   print("The sum is",recursive_sum(num))
```