# Sum of the integers from 1 to n

Tags: python, sum

I'm trying to write a program to add up the numbers from 1 to n. I've managed to get it to print the numbers several times but not to add them all. It keeps on just adding two of the numbers.

My 1st attempt is:

```
def problem1_3(n):
    my_sum = 0
    while my_sum <= n:
        my_sum = my_sum + (my_sum + 1)
    print() 
    print(my_sum)
```

How can I fix this problem?

---

<sup>For the recursive version of this question, see [Recursive function to calculate sum of 1 to n?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19966290/6045800)</sup>

Comment: `my_sum = my_sum + (my_sum + 1)` doubles your previous value and adds `1` to it. Why not `my_sum += 1` (which is equivalent to `my_sum = my_sum + 1`). Outside of that, your indentation is off and you don't show how you call the function.

Comment: `while my_sum <= n` This condition doesn't look correct. Did you mean to use a counter there? Consider 1 2 3 4. This will get out of the loop at 3 because the sum (1+2+3) will be larger than 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 different variables in your code -- a variable where you can store the sum as you iterate through the values and add them (my_sum in my code), and another variable (i in my code) to iterate over the numbers from 0 to n.

```
def problem1_3(n):
    my_sum = 0
    i=0
    #replace this pass (a do-nothing) statement with your code
    while i <= n:
        my_sum = my_sum + i
        print(my_sum)
        i+=1
    return my_sum
```

You are using the my_sum variable in your code to both store the sum and iterate through the numbers.

Answer (score 20):

There is no need for a loop at all. You can use the [triangular number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula):

```
n = int(input())
print(n * (n + 1) // 2)
```

---

***A note about the division (`//`) (in Python 3)***: As you might know, [there are two types of division operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282945/6045800). In short, `/` will give a float result and `//` will give an int. In this case, we could use both operators, the only difference will be the returned type, ***but not the value***. Since [multiplying an odd with an even always gives an even number](https://www.splashlearn.com/math-vocabulary/number-sense/even-and-odd-numbers#3-fascinating-properties-of-an-even-number-), dividing that by 2 will always be a whole number. In other words - `n*(n+1) // 2 == n*(n+1) / 2` (but one would be `x` and the other `x.0`, respectively).

Answer (score 14):

You can do it with one line, where you [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) of numbers from 0 to `n` (the end is exclusive):

```
def problem1_3(n):
    return sum(range(n+1))
```

Comment: With Python3, range produces a generator not a list, I thought it had to be explicitly converted to a list for sum, but without it it also works. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: No worries. Most standard functions & methods that accept a list will also accept a generator, and it's generally more efficient to feed them a generator if you can. So (for example) you can pass a generator to `max`. One big exception is the `str.join` method. It _can_  accept a generator, but it needs to scan the sequence of strings twice: the 1st time it calculates the total length of the final destination string, the 2nd time it copies the data. So if you pass it a generator it has to build a list before it can process the data. The same goes for the `bytes.join` method.

Comment: (cont) Similarly, `sorted` can accept a generator, but it has to construct a list, which it then calls the `list.sort` method on, so there's no advantage in using `sorted` on a generator, rather than `.sort` on a list, apart from the more compact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of numbers from 1 to n will be greater than n. For example, the sum of numbers from 1 to 5 is 15 which is obviously greater than 5. Your while loop terminates prematurely. You need to maintain a separate counter for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy` to [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) the numbers in the [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) of 1 to n+1 (exclusive):

```
import numpy as np 

np.sum(np.arange(1, n+1))
```

Comment: A little overkill to import such a strong tool for something that can be just the same be done with equivalent built-in functions: `sum(range(1, n+1))`

Answer (score 0):

Real programmers use recursion (and hopes for a not too big n since there is no tail call optimization in Python):

```
def problem1_3(n):
    return n + problem1_3(n-1) if n > 1 else 1
```

Comment: And, yes, as it is currently written, this function wouldn't be able to use TCO, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

so it will be more optimal

```
def f(a):
    return (a + 1) * (abs(a) + 2 * (a <= 0)) // 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This while loop works:

```
def main():
    n = int(input('Enter a number:'))              
    while n <= 1:
        n = int(input('Please input a new number'))

    total = 0
    my_sum = 0
    while (n-1) >= total:
        total = total + 1
        my_sum += total
        print(my_sum)
        
    return 

main()
```

Comment: Btw, if you want to just have the second while loop to say "while n >= total:" all you need to do is just put "print(my_sum) right before "my_sum += total".

Answer (score 0):

In this case where you iterate over a known sequence, it is better to use a `for` loop and add the numbers as you go:

```
def summation(num): 
    sumX = 0
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        sumX = sumX + i
    return sumX

summation(3)  # You place the num you need here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = input("Enter Number to calculate sum")
n = int (n)
#average = 0.
#sum = 0
sum = 0.
for num in range(0,n+1,1):
    sum = sum+num
print("SUM of first ", n, "numbers is: ", sum )

# Print sum of numbers from 1 to N inclusive

def sum2N(N):
    r = 0
    for i in range(N+1):
        #for i in range(0,N+1,1):
        #r+=i
        r=r+i
    return(r)

print(sum2N(10))
```

Answer (score -2):

How about you try it using a "While Loop":

```
def problem1_3(n):
my_sum = 0
while my_sum <= n:
    print(my_sum,end=" ")  # end = " " keeps from starting a new line
    my_sum = my_sum + 1
print(my_sum)
```

Comment: Apart from the bad indentation, this simply doesn't answer the question. This just prints the sequence of numbers from 0 to `n+1`. The question asks for the ***sum*** of the numbers from 1 to `n`...