# Sum sequence recursive in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am implementing a recursive code to sum of the sequence: x + x^2 / 2 + x^3 / 3... + x^n / n, i thought a setting combining two recursive functions, but is returning approximate values for n < 4, is very high for n >= 4, obviously is incorrect, but it was the best definition that i thought. Code Below:

```
def pot(x, n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    else:
        return x * pot(x, n - 1)

def Sum_Seq (x, n): 
    if n == 1: return x 
    else: 
        return x + Sum_Seq(pot(x, n - 1), n - 1) / (n - 1)
```

Comment: Provide some examples of input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: `/` is floating point division in python 3. Is that what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive function to calculate sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966290/recursive-function-to-calculate-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I don't see why you need two recursive functions in this case. Simply use `x**n` to calculate `x` to the power `n`:

```
def sum_seq(x, n):
    if n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return (x**n/n) + sum_seq(x, n-1)
```

This works great in Python 3:

```
>>> power(10, 6)
Out[1]: 189560.0
```

Keep in mind that, in Python 2, the `/` operator will infer whether you are doing an integer division or floating-point division. To guarantee your division will be the floating-point division in Python 2, just import the `/` operator from Python 3 with:

```
from __future__ import division
```

or even cast your division to float:

```
float(x**n)/n
```

Answer (score 3):

If recursion is your mean and not your aim, you can use this function:

```
def polynom(x,n_max):
    return sum(pow(x,n)*1./n for n in range(1, n_max + 1))
```

Then you get what you want:

```
x = 1
for i in range(5):
    print polynom(x,i)
Out:
    0
    1.0
    1.5
    1.83333333333
    2.08333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Sum_Seq()` function should be this:

```
def Sum_Seq (x, n): 
    if n == 1: 
        return x 
    else: 
        return pot(x, n)*1.0/n + Sum_Seq(x, n-1) # 1.0 is used for getting output as a fractional value.
```

NOTE: You don't **need** to make another recursive function calculate power. In python you can just do `x**n` to get x to the power n.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pot` function seems to perform the job of the `**` [power operator](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/power.html).

Maybe something like this will help -

```
In [1]: # x + x^2 / 2 + x^3 / 3... + x^n / n

In [2]: def sum_seq(x, n):
   ...:     if n <= 0:
   ...:         return 0
   ...:     return (x**n)/n + sum_seq(x, n - 1)
   ...:

In [3]: sum_seq(10, 2)
Out[3]: 60.0
```

EDIT: 
I think the reason for the erroneous results in your code was this line -

`return x + Sum_Seq(pot(x, n - 1), n - 1) / (n - 1)`

Adding the `Sum_Seq` to x, does not follow the pattern you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can  use simple linear recursion method

```py
def lin_sum(s,n):

    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return lin_sum(s,n-1)+s[n-1]
s=[1,2,3,4,5]    
print(lin_sum(s,5))
```